# Cross compiling ARM static lib with GCC for Mac iOS xCode projects

Tags: osx, gcc, arm, cross-compilation, ios

I'm cross compiling ARM targeted toy example static lib for the usage in Mac iOS xCode projects.

In the lib there are only 2 files `atoy.c` and `atoy.h` with simple function taking 2 `int` arguments and returning `int` result of their combination.

Cross compilation steps are:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -g -Wall -march=armv7-a -c atoy.c
arm-none-eabi-ar rcs libatoy.a atoy.o
arm-none-eabi-ranlib libatoy.a
```

The resulted `libatoy.a` used on xCode 7.1.1 with project type iOS app gives the following errors:

```
... normal armv7
...
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.1
...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.1.sdk
...
/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.../Build/Intermediates/....build/Debug-iphoneos/PerformanceTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/....LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.1 -dead_strip -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -latoy -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker
...
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/.../libatoy.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): /Users/.../libatoy.a
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
    "_aadd", referenced from:
    -[ViewController runTest] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

There should be some .a file format differences that is generated on Linux Mint 17.2 x64. Or the case is hard Canadian cross compilation build-host-target problem?

I'm using `gcc-arm-none-eabi` package.

Answer (score 1):

I do remember reading about compatibility problems with XCode 7 when trying to cross compile NetBSD 7 for ARM. I gave up on that and cross compiled it in a Linux server at work, so I cannot give more details.

Comment: that was a reverse to my problem situation hope linux way will work. I think I need to generate binary for mac os x os

Comment: Nevertheless when I tried a couple of months ago XCode was still in beta phase. Maybe things have changed by now.  What I felt all the way long was a lack of decent documentation, too much experimentation.

Comment: Linux is betterin that way gcc supports many targets including arm and darwin but how to combine them to have arm architecture in darwin mac os x format

Comment: No idea actually, that is a though one. Albeit Apple does contribute a lot downstream in patches, they also have a lot of specific modifications. That is a though one. I developed for a while for the OS/X iOS, more centered in Linux/Unix nowadays.